# How do I get data from an input to be reflected in the model if I use ng-model-options?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the ng-model-options directive to ensure that I can complete the input of a value before the list reorders itself and the td containing the input hides.

The value is reflected in the view, however it isn't reflected in the model until I click on the sibling td that displays the char.initiative data.

The AngularJS documentation suggests that I invoke ngModel.NgModelController.  It also suggests that the easiest way to reference the control's ngModel.NgModelController method is by making sure the input is placed inside of a form element that has a name attribute.  The problem there is that I'm not using a form element.

How can I invoke ngModel.NgModelController to sync my view and model data up without using a form element?  Is there any other way to sync my view and model that does not require the use of ngModel.NgModelController?

```
    <tr ng-repeat="char in localChars | orderBy: '-initiative'">
      <td>{{char.name}}</td>
      <td ng-hide='char.show' ng-click='change(char)'>{{char.initiative}}</td>
      <td ng-show='char.show'><input ng-blur='change(char)' ng-model='char.initiative' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: This is how `updateOn: 'blur'` ng-model-options work.. why you are expecting to work in different way?

Comment: I don't expect it to work in a different way.  I understand this is it's nature.  Using ng-model-options fixes one issue, but then presents a new one as I described above.   I need to know how to sync the model data and the view data.

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using? I can't seem to reproduce the behaviour you're describing with version 1.7.2.

Comment: I am also using version 1.7.2.

Comment: @jace I added an answer with a snippet using version 1.7.2. I can't reproduce the behaviour.